# How can I fix this dependancy error when deploying a nextjs 13 app with vercel?

Tags: npm, next.js, deployment, vercel, lint

I am trying to deploy my NextJS 13 app with vercel, but I get this error on deploying. In vscode, I have ran the linting and it returned no problems. Also did 'npm run build' in vscode which worked fine.

```
...
[14:58:01.978] Previous build cache not available
[14:58:02.279] Cloning completed: 593.19ms
[14:58:02.615] Running "vercel build"
[14:58:03.127] Vercel CLI 31.1.1
[14:58:03.363] Installing dependencies...
[14:58:04.074] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-next@12.0.4
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.44.0
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
[14:58:04.077] npm ERR!   eslint@"8.44.0" from the root project
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!     @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@8.44.0
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   5 more (eslint-import-resolver-typescript, ...)
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-next
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   eslint-config-next@"^12.0.4" from the root project
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-next
[14:58:04.078] npm ERR!     eslint-config-next@"^12.0.4" from the root project
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.079] npm ERR! 
[14:58:04.080] npm ERR! For a full report see:
[14:58:04.080] npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-31T13_58_03_754Z-eresolve-report.txt
[14:58:04.080] 
[14:58:04.080] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[14:58:04.080] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-31T13_58_03_754Z-debug-0.log
[14:58:04.093] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have tried installing next lint again with npm but that has made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your project's settings on vercel
2. Choose "General" on left menu and scroll to "Build & Development Settings"
3. Turn the "override" on for "install command"
4. Write `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` in the input.